# Can System.Int32.ToString() specify a custom radix?

Tags: .net, string, tostring

I want to convert an `int` to a `string` with base36 (0-9 and a-z).

How is this done in .NET?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only thing close is [Convert.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14kwkz77.aspx), which only allows conversions to base 2, 8, 10, and 16.  You will have to roll your own conversion, or use [this sample on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/radix.aspx).